# Group documents with different field types with mongodb aggregations

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I tried a bunch of things, but I'm not really a MongoDB genius and to be honest I'm not even sure this is really possible. I have some documents with a field that sometimes can be a string, and sometimes can be an array of strings, and I wanna to group both cases together.

Example data:

```
{ "identifier" : "b553622e-b1c9-4030-8460-a7783214359b", "participants" : [ "p1" ] }
{ "identifier" : "919f77bc-adca-4cbc-ac38-9139552cdb5b", "participants" : [ "p2" ] }
{ "identifier" : [ "919f77bc-adca-4cbc-ac38-9139552cdb5b", "b553622e-b1c9-4030-8460-a7783214359b" ], "participants" : [ "p3" ] }
{ "identifier": "9837dac78-4cbc-dsa38-9139552cd564", "participants": ["p2"]},
{ "identifier": "9837dac78-4cbc-dsa38-9139552cd564", "participants": ["p3"]},
```

The expected result would be something like that:

```
{ "_id" : [ "919f77bc-adca-4cbc-ac38-9139552cdb5b", "b553622e-b1c9-4030-8460-a7783214359b" ], "participants" : ["p1", "p2", "p3",] },
{ "_id" : [ "9837dac78-4cbc-dsa38-9139552cd564" ], "participants" : [ "p2", "p3",] }
```

The _id being a list is not really necessary, the main goal here is to be able to group all documents that have the matching identifier, considering both cases with and without list. Is it even possible? Thanks!

I tried some variations of the $group operations, but couldn't get to something that works like I intend to.

Comment: `[ {$match: { identifier: <string value> } }, {$group: { _id: null, participants: ... } } ]`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, what would be <string value>? I don't want to filter any of the example inputs out, I want to consider and group all three together regardless if "identifier" is a list or string.

Comment: Do you want to group all documents in your entire collection together? If so, drop the $match

Comment: If you had another document with an _"outlier"_ `"identifier"`, e.g., `{ "identifier" : "b553622e-b1c9-4030-8460-a77832fffffb", "participants" : [ "p4" ] }`, what should the output look like then?

Comment: @rickhg12hs should look the same as the one from my question, but with the "p4" inside the "participants" array

`{ "_id" : [ "919f77bc-adca-4cbc-ac38-9139552cdb5b", "b553622e-b1c9-4030-8460-a7783214359b" ], "participants" : ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"] }`

Comment: What about the _"new"_ `"identifier"`?

Answer (score 0):

Divert your collection into 2 cases:

1. `identifier` being array
2. `identifier` is not an array

For 1, use `$match` with `$type` to get the documents. `$unwind` the `identifier` field. `$unionWith` case 2(same fetch as 1, just use `$ne`). Perform the `$group` to get your desired result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "array",
          {
            "$type": "$identifier"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$identifier"
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                "array",
                {
                  "$type": "$identifier"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$participants"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allId: {
        "$addToSet": "$identifier"
      },
      participants: {
        $addToSet: "$participants"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$allId",
      participants: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ll4Q9I7_MK0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ray. Your solution is really great, but it will always group everything together, and in my use case I can have completely different identifiers that need to be grouped separately from each other. That's my fault because my example don't make it clear, I will update it.

Comment: @MathiasHillesheim Can you explain what is the logic of whether grouping IDs into array or not? Your latest example seems having  inconsistent behaviour and probably will be hard to maintain